# Android webview: How do I get the double tab to zoom IN and not OUT

Tags: android

I have a webview that starts with a zoom level of 100. When I double tap, it zooms out. How can I make it zoom IN on the first double tap?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)` and `setUserWideViewPort(true)`

```
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```